# GraphQL "There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'."

Tags: django, graphql

I'm trying to get a list of tour reservations to a certain place using variables and I'm getting the error stated in the title

```
    query GetReservationByTour($tour_place: String!) {
      reservationsByPlace(place: $tour_place) {
       id
       tour {
        id
        place
       }
     }
    }
```

Query:

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
prices = graphene.List(PriceType)
tours = graphene.List(TourType)
users = graphene.List(UserType)
reservations = graphene.List(ReservationType)
reservations_by_place = graphene.Field(graphene.List(ReservationType), place=String(required=True))


def resolve_prices(root, info, **kwargs):
    return Price.objects.all()

def resolve_tours(root, info, **kwargs):
    return Tour.objects.all()

def resolve_users(root, info, **kwargs):
    return User.objects.all()

def resolve_reservations(root, info, **kwargs):
    return Reservation.objects.all()

def resolve_reservations_by_place(root, info, place, **kwargs):
     return Reservation.objects.get(place=place)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to show the typeDef for the `reservations` query to see how it is defined.

However even without it your syntax should be:

```
query GetReservationByTour($tour_place: String!) {
  reservations(place: $tour_place) {
    id
    tour {
      id
      place
    }
  }
}
```

because `tour` is a `field` in the return object from the `reservations` query and not an actual *query* (you can't *nest* queries). The arguments to the query ('place') are available to all the field resolvers so your `resolve_tours` resolver will be able to pick off the place even when it's nested within a reservation query.

Comment: What is typeDef? and after this modification I get the error: "Variable '$tour_place' is never used in operation 'GetReservationByTour'."

Comment: By typeDefs I mean the definition of your *types*, but here particularly `query reservations(…){…}`. I edited the answer to reflect putting the `place` variable on the `reservations` query.

Comment: Understand and with variable next to reservations i still get error "Unknown argument 'place' on field 'Query.reservations'."

Comment: That's telling you that your definition of your query is incomplete. Your query doesn't expect an argument and yet you are trying to feed it one.

Comment: I added query definition to question

Comment: Yep, you haven't specified any [arguments](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/objecttypes/#graphql-arguments-kwargs) for your `reservations` query!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    prices = graphene.List(PriceType)
    tours = graphene.List(TourType)
    users = graphene.List(UserType)
    reservations = graphene.List(ReservationType)
    reservations_by_place = graphene.Field(graphene.List(ReservationType),
                                           place=String(required=True))

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_prices(root, info, **kwargs):
        return Price.objects.all()

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_tours(root, info, **kwargs):
        return Tour.objects.all()

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_users(root, info, **kwargs):
        return User.objects.all()

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_reservations(root, info, **kwargs):
        return Reservation.objects.all()

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_reservations_by_place(root, info, place, **kwargs):
        return Reservation.objects.get(place=place)
```